# How can i generate custom string with loop?

Tags: php

I want to automatically add "\n\n" between array values.
My array is sent from the form and I can break it down and get the values.
İ need to create string like this:

```
$data = $new['1']."\n\n".$new['2']."\n\n\"...
```

I'm having trouble because array values ​​are a number variable.
How can i solve this problem?

```
$title = $request['title'];
$title = explode("\r\n", $title);
foreach($title as $titl){
    $tit = rtrim($titl);
    $a[] = $tit;
}
$a1 = array_filter($a);
$new = array_values($a1);
$count = count($title);
```

Comment: You mean from `$new` you want to create a string like `$value['1']."\n\n".$value['2']."\n\n\"...` right? If Yes, then show data if no then I am unclear what you are asking!

Comment: i updated my question. I need to create string with $new values and add between "\n\n"

Comment: use `implode` ?

Comment: I'm surprised how this didn't occur to me. I've been going a long way. Thanks